# IBM Watson Assistant: How to create dialog that will only accept 1 kind of entity

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I'm trying to create a dialog that accepts only 1 entity

```
Entities
@cat : cat
@dog : dog
@alligator : alligator, crocodile
```

I am trying to solve it with this condition:

```
If Watson recognizes:
@cat and !@dog and !@alligator

respond
cat entity will display
```

is there any other way to achieve this without specifying the other entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use various [kinds of conditions](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-overview#dialog-overview-conditions) in the evaluation of a dialog node. In my [collection of tips and tricks for IBM Watson Assistant](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/watson-conversation-variables#access-to-system-entities) I am using `entities.size()` to access how many entities have been detected.

You could use something like `@cat AND entities.size()==1` to check that **cat** was detected and it is the only entity.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I was able to play around entities now